# JS: new-state object created; prevent "pop" from affecting old-state object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In the game code below: even though the javascript `new` keyword was used to make a new object to hold the next-state object, methods applied to the next-state object still refer to first-state object for "naked" properties passed to the constructor when making the next-state object.

When a transformation is applied to a property before using it as a parameter for the next-object constructor, preserving the first-state property is easy (e.g. with timeOfDay it is easy to avoid overwriting the first state).

I've resorted to a "map" workaround to avoid referencing the first-state object when modifying the list of mafia, but it is probably not the cleanest or easiest to understand.

A few other previously answered questions suggest using something like `Object.assign({},this.mafia)` but this does not allow usage of the "pop method" in the code below.

Please suggest an alternative to avoid overwriting the first-state object as shown below.

```
class mafiaVillageState{

    constructor(timeOfDay, villagers, mafia){
        this.timeOfDay = timeOfDay;
        this.villagers = villagers;
        this.mafia = mafia;
    }    

    killPlayer(){
        let gameStep = new mafiaVillageState(1-this.timeOfDay,
            this.villagers.map(v => {return v}),

            // this.mafia
            this.mafia.map(v => {return v})      
            // Object.assign({},this.mafia)

        );
        if (this.timeOfDay == 1){
            gameStep.mafia.pop();
        } else {
            gameStep.villagers.pop();
        }
        return gameStep 
    }
}

let first = new mafiaVillageState(
    1,
    ["Sana","Dahyun"], //the villagers
    ["Chaeyoung","Tzuyu"] //the mafia
)
```

"Playing the game" is done by getting the next game state:

```
let next = first.killPlayer();

console.log(first.timeOfDay);
console.log(first.mafia);
console.log(next.timeOfDay);
console.log(next.mafia);
```

- output without any workaround to avoid referencing the first object modifies the first state (not desired as I do not want to overwrite the initial state, to help debug when the selection of the player to kill is much more complicated)

```
1
Array(1) ["Chaeyoung"]
0
Array(1) ["Chaeyoung"]
```

- output with the "map workaround": this is the desired output; one mafia is killed and the first state is not changed

```
1
Array(2) ["Chaeyoung", "Tzuyu"]
0
Array(1) ["Chaeyoung"]
```

-using `Object.assign({},this.mafia)` results in error below

```
' TypeError: gameStep.mafia.pop is not a function '
```

Comment: the output of Object.assign({}, this.mafia) is a normal js object which does not have a pop method on its prototype, so you should not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new object for the new state if you want to preserve the old one for debugging reasons, there is no way around that. I don't think that using .map is a bad solution but if you are looking for something cleaner you can use the es6 array spread operator or `Array.prototype.splice`.

```
killPlayer(){
    let gameStep = new mafiaVillageState(
        1 - this.timeOfDay,
        [...this.villagers], // alternatively: this.villagers.splice(),
        [...this.mafia],
    );

    ...
}
```

The spread operator dumps the items in the array being spread into the new one (you can also do things like [...arr1, ...arr2] to combine arrays). You should note that the items are not copied, so if you mutate something in either array the mutation will affect all states that contain that object.